# Latest Gmail update is not working on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: notifications, gmail

I have the Gmail app installed and in the latest update it said we could reply to emails directly from the drop-down status bar without having to open the app.  I don't see any feature like this.  How do I activate it?

OS: 4.1.1
Samsung Galaxy S3

Answer (score 1):

I have GMail 4.3.1 on my AT&T 4.1.1 S3. I find that the `Archive` and `Reply` action buttons only appear on the new mail notification sometimes. As near as I can tell, two conditions need to be true for them to appear:

- There must be only one new email. Multiple new emails will change the notification style to a list of new emails. So if you get a lot of email, you'll never see the action buttons.
- There must be enough room in the notification pane to show an expanded notification without needing to scroll the notifications. So if you have a lot of ongoing notifications, you'll never see the expanded new mail notification with the two action buttons.

Comment: Note that if there's not enough space in the notification pane for the full-size notification, you can (depending whether you've got Android 4.1 or 4.2) either do a two-fingered zoom pinch on the notification to expand it, or long-press on it and drag down to expand it to see the full functionality with the buttons.

Comment: That's a good tip, @GAThrawn. I've had difficulty doing the pinch-to-expand maneuver. I suspect I'm not alone in that, and that's why they changed it in 4.2.

Comment: I find that I can consistently pinch-to-expand if I put two fingers in the middle of the notification, then slide them horizontally toward the edges of the notification.  I kept trying to slide them vertically because that's how I pinch-to-collapse. Turns out that a horizontal pinch works to collapse too, but feels odd since it collapses vertically.